# How can I suppress FedAuth cookies from being uploaded with Blueimp Fileupload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, file-upload, blueimp

**THE PROBLEM:**  I currently have this issue in which the FedAuth cookies bloat beyond 16K.  This is a problem since the IIS server doesn't accept headers above 16K.  The Blueimp Fileuploader uploads all of the FedAuth cookies for each chunk.  So what happens is that the chunks fail to upload since the header is too big.

Is there a way that I can suppress certain cookies from being uploaded in the header with the Blueimp Uploader?  Would appreciate any advice/help on this!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to cache your securitytoken on the server and only include a reference to it in the FedAuth cookie:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/20/switching-to-referencemode-in-asp-net-4-5/